# Scikit-learn pipeline that begins with a custom transformer that uses X and y to filter out columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to create a pipeline that contains, respectively, a custom transformer, a Binning Process estimator from the OptBinning library and then a logistic regression. I want to execute this pipeline inside a GridSearchCV. My intent is to filter out features that are too correlated and use as decision criteria the information value of each variable, or how able to predict the target variable the feature is. As this includes this use of how each variable can predict the target it has to be executed inside the grid search otherwise I would bias the model, however, I don't seem able to do this as the pipeline always breaks, independently of the transformer working properly by it self.

The class and the function I created for the custom transformer are as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from optbinning import BinningProcess, OptimalBinning


def corr_bivariate_filter(
    X: pd.DataFrame,
    y: pd.DataFrame,
    filtered_features: pd.DataFrame,
    corr_threshold=0.8,
    monotonic=True,
    binning_fit_params={},
):
    corr_threshold = 0.8
    monotonic = True

    num_vars = list(X.select_dtypes(include=[int, float]).columns)
    cat_vars = list(X.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns)

    if monotonic:
        binning_fit_params = {
            v: {"monotonic_trend": "auto_asc_desc"} for v in num_vars + cat_vars
        }

    filtered_features = filtered_features["features"].tolist()
    # filtered_features = list(X.columns)

    binning_process = BinningProcess(
        filtered_features,
        categorical_variables=cat_vars,
        binning_fit_params=binning_fit_params,
        #  selection_criteria=selection_criteria,
        #  fixed_variables=fixed_variables,
    )

    X_filtered = X[filtered_features].copy()
    # X_filtered = X.copy()
    # display(X_filtered.shape)
    # display(X_filtered.sample(5))
    # display(y.sample(1))
    # display(y['30ever3'].value_counts(dropna=False))
    # display(y['30ever3'].shape)

    print(type(X_filtered))
    print(type(y))
    binning_process.fit(X_filtered, y)

    bivariate_df = binning_process.summary()

    num_vars_filtered = list(X_filtered.select_dtypes(include=["int", "float"]).columns)

    iv_dict = {}

    for i in bivariate_df["name"].to_list():
        iv_dict[i] = bivariate_df[bivariate_df["name"] == i]["iv"].iloc[0]

    corr_matrix = X_filtered[num_vars_filtered].corr().abs()
    upper = corr_matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(corr_matrix.shape), k=1).astype(bool))
    upper = upper[(upper >= corr_threshold)]

    correlation_groups = []
    post_filter_columns = []

    for c in upper.columns:
        correlations = {}
        df = upper[upper[c].notna()]
        variables = list(df.index.values)
        if variables:
            for v in variables:
                correlations[v] = iv_dict[v]

            correlations[c] = iv_dict[c]
            correlation_groups.append(correlations)

    for d in correlation_groups:
        post_filter_columns.append(max(d, key=d.get))

    post_filter_columns = list(dict.fromkeys(post_filter_columns))

    unpacked_vars = []

    for d in correlation_groups:
        for i in d.keys():
            unpacked_vars.append(i)

    to_drop = list(set(unpacked_vars) - set(post_filter_columns))

    columns_after_correlation_filter = [
        c for c in X_filtered[num_vars_filtered] if c not in to_drop
    ]

    # non_correlated_features_df = pd.DataFrame(
    #     {"features": columns_after_correlation_filter}
    # )

    return columns_after_correlation_filter


# The ColumnsSelector class inherits from the sklearn.base classes
# (BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin). This makes it compatible with
# scikit-learn’s Pipelines
class CorrBivariateColumnsSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    # initializer
    def __init__(
        self,
        y_,
        filtered_features,
        corr_threshold,
        monotonic,
        binning_fit_params={},
    ):
        # save the features list internally in the class
        self.y_ = y_
        self.filtered_features = filtered_features
        self.corr_threshold = corr_threshold
        self.monotonic = monotonic
        self.binning_fit_params = binning_fit_params

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        # return the dataframe with the specified features
        columns_ = corr_bivariate_filter(
            X,
            self.y_,
            self.filtered_features,
            self.corr_threshold,
            self.monotonic,
            self.binning_fit_params,
        )

        X_filtered = X[columns_].copy()
        # self.columns = X_filtered.columns

        return X_filtered

    def fit_transform(self, X, y):
        self.fit(X, y)
        return self.transform(X)
```

I apply the custom transformer in this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from utils import ks_score
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline, Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, GridSearchCV, KFold
from optbinning import BinningProcess, OptimalBinning
from utils import corr_bivariate_filter, CorrBivariateColumnsSelector

ks_scorer = make_scorer(ks_score, needs_proba=True, greater_is_better=True)

features = catalog.load("features_after_univariate_filter")
feature_list = features['features'].to_list()
df = catalog.load("sample_with_features")

df = df.set_index('request_id')[feature_list + ['30ever3']].copy()

X = df[feature_list]
y = df[['30ever3']]

y = y.values.ravel()

num_vars = list(X.select_dtypes(include=[int,float]).columns)
cat_vars = list(X.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns)

binning_fit_params = {v: {"monotonic_trend": "auto_asc_desc"}
                      for v in num_vars+cat_vars}

binning_process = BinningProcess(num_vars+cat_vars,
                                 categorical_variables=cat_vars,
                                 binning_fit_params=binning_fit_params,
                                )

correlation_bivariate_filter = CorrBivariateColumnsSelector(features, 0.8, True, {})

lr = LogisticRegression()

pipe = make_pipeline(
    correlation_bivariate_filter, 
    binning_process, 
    lr,
)

inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=3)

p_grid = {
          # "binningprocess__selection_criteria": selection_criteria,
          "logisticregression__C": [1/2, 1/1, 1/0.5, 1/0.1],
          "logisticregression__penalty": ["l1"],
          "logisticregression__solver": ["liblinear"],
          "logisticregression__verbose": [0, 2, 5, 10],
          "logisticregression__max_iter": [50, 80, 100, 150, 200],
              }

scoring = {
            'auc': 'roc_auc', 
            'log_loss': 'neg_log_loss',
            'brier_score': 'neg_brier_score', 
            'ks': ks_scorer,
        }

clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
cv_results = cross_validate(clf,
                            X, 
                            y,
                            cv=outer_cv, 
                            scoring=scoring,
                            return_estimator=True, 
                            )
```

And the error I'm getting is the following:

```
WARNING  /home/user/anaconda3/envs/score/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ warnings.py:109
                             sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:372: FitFailedWarning:                         
                             240 fits failed out of a total of 240.                                                
                             The score on these train-test partitions for these parameters will be                 
                             set to nan.                                                                           
                             If these failures are not expected, you can try to debug them by                      
                             setting error_score='raise'.                                                          
                                                                                                                   
                             Below are more details about the failures:                                            
                             ----------------------------------------------------------------------                
                             ----------                                                                            
                             240 fits failed with the following error:                                             
                             Traceback (most recent call last):                                                    
                               File                                                                                
                             "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/score/lib/python3.9/site-packages                
                             /sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 680, in _fit_and_score                 
                                 estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)                                     
                               File                                                                                
                             "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/score/lib/python3.9/site-packages                
                             /sklearn/pipeline.py", line 390, in fit                                               
                                 Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)                                          
                               File                                                                                
                             "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/score/lib/python3.9/site-packages                
                             /sklearn/pipeline.py", line 348, in _fit                                              
                                 X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(                                 
                               File                                                                                
                             "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/score/lib/python3.9/site-packages                
                             /joblib/memory.py", line 349, in __call__                                             
                                 return self.func(*args, **kwargs)                                                 
                               File                                                                                
                             "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/score/lib/python3.9/site-packages                
                             /sklearn/pipeline.py", line 893, in _fit_transform_one                                
                                 res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)                               
                               File                                                                                
                             "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/score/lib/python3.9/site-packages                
                             /optbinning/binning/binning_process.py", line 726, in fit_transform                   
                                 return self.fit(X, y, sample_weight, check_input).transform(                      
                               File                                                                                
                             "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/score/lib/python3.9/site-packages                
                             /optbinning/binning/binning_process.py", line 632, in fit                             
                                 return self._fit(X, y, sample_weight, check_input)                                
                               File                                                                                
                             "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/score/lib/python3.9/site-packages                
                             /optbinning/binning/binning_process.py", line 1095, in _fit                           
                                 raise ValueError("The number of columns must be equal to the"                     
                             ValueError: The number of columns must be equal to thelength of                       
                             variable_names.                                                                       
                                                                                                                   
                               warnings.warn(some_fits_failed_message, FitFailedWarning)                           
                                                                                                                   
                    WARNING  /home/user/anaconda3/envs/score/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ warnings.py:109
                             sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:969: UserWarning: One or more of                   
                             the test scores are non-finite: [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan                  
                             nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan                                                   
                              nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan                  
                             nan                                                                                   
                              nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan                  
                             nan                                                                                   
                              nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan                  
                             nan                                                                                   
                              nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]                                                     
                               warnings.warn(
```

The thing is I only get this error when I execute the transformer inside the pipeline, when I execute it on its on it returns the X dataframe.

Comment: I see there is a mismatch the number of variable names and the number of columns in the dataframe passed to BinningProcess. Have you verified that `num_vars+cat_vars` is the same length as the number of columns returned by `correlation_bivariate_filter`?